# Javascript catch protoype calls

Tags: javascript, prototype, call

Is there a way in javascript to catch every call on an object's prototype?

So if there is a Something object, and someone calls Something.someFunction() where someFunction does not exists I can return false.

This is possible using Proxy, but I need a cross-browser solution.
Using a delegate function which first parameter is a function name, second is the function parameter also not good.

Example:

```
var Something = (function() {
    var Something = function () {};

    Something prototype = {
        'test': function() {}
    };

    return new Something();
})();

Something.someFunction(); // false
```

Comment: Why would you want to return false if someone calls a method that doesn't exist? The appropriate response, which is what the browser does by default, is to error that such a method doesn't exist. This seems a strange error to suppress.

Comment: *"Is there a way in javascript to catch every call on an object's prototype?"* Nope.

Comment: @FelixKling - surely that is the answer, not a comment.